# Find dependent rows/columns of a matrix using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a set of linear equation to be solved using  `\` that is `F=JT\RH` where RH is 18x1 and JT is 18x17 and F (unknown) is 17x1, but matlab gives the warning that rank is deficient and the rank is 16. So I want to know which columns/rows are linearly dependent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns of A are linearly dependent iff **null(A)** is not zero.
Running **B=null(A)** in Matlab will return you a basis of the null space. For every column in B, take the indices of the non-zero elements in that column. These will be the columns numbers you are looking for.
For example, try:

```
a = rand(18,16);
a(:,17) = a(:,2) + a(:,4);
null(a)
```

Comment: I tried your example and the 1st 9th 12th and 13th rows are zero. it should not be like this.

Comment: If you run the example, the non-zeros will be in 2,4 and 17th rows, signifying that the 2nd, 4th and 17th column are linearly dependent

Comment: but when i use this for my own matrix, there are only 4 zero elements. so as you said other 13 columns are dependent, but the rank is 16 not 4.

Comment: The other 13 columns are dependent. That only means that their rank is smaller than 13. In your case that rank is 12.