# How to find linearly independent rows from a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

How to identify the linearly independent rows from a matrix? For instance,

[image]

The 4th rows is independent.

Comment: If I am not mistaken `linear independent` is a feature of a set of vectors. I am not sure what `identify the linearly independent rows` means in this context. What exactly should be the output?

Comment: Sorry for not expressing myself clearly.  In this example, the **rank** is 3 so delete one of dependent rows (say the 3rd row). Actually, the question what I want to track is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522363/get-the-maximum-permutation-matrix-from-logical-matrix).

Comment: @sparkandshine Are you only considering whole numbers?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, your 3rd row is linearly dependent with 1t and 2nd row. However, your 1st and 4th column are linearly dependent.

Two methods you could use:

**Eigenvalue**

If one eigenvalue of the matrix is zero, its corresponding eigenvector is linearly dependent. The documentation [eig](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy.linalg.eig) states the returned eigenvalues are repeated according to their multiplicity and not necessarily ordered. However, assuming the eigenvalues correspond to your row vectors, one method would be:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1]
    ])

lambdas, V =  np.linalg.eig(matrix.T)
# The linearly dependent row vectors 
print matrix[lambdas == 0,:]
```

**Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**

To test linear dependence of vectors and figure out which ones, you could use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). Basically, if the inner product of the vectors is equal to the product of the norm of the vectors, the vectors are linearly dependent. Here is an example for the columns:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1]
    ])

print np.linalg.det(matrix)

for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        if i != j:
            inner_product = np.inner(
                matrix[:,i],
                matrix[:,j]
            )
            norm_i = np.linalg.norm(matrix[:,i])
            norm_j = np.linalg.norm(matrix[:,j])

            print 'I: ', matrix[:,i]
            print 'J: ', matrix[:,j]
            print 'Prod: ', inner_product
            print 'Norm i: ', norm_i
            print 'Norm j: ', norm_j
            if np.abs(inner_product - norm_j * norm_i) < 1E-5:
                print 'Dependent'
            else:
                print 'Independent'
```

To test the rows is a similar approach.

Then you could extend this to test all combinations of vectors, but I imagine this solution scale badly with size.

Comment: This code only works with square matrices? The original question gave an example with a square matrix, but you can do this with rectangular matrices as well?

Comment: @Annan the Cauchy-Schwarz method works also for rectangular matrices, just change the range of indices in the for loops.

Comment: @hakanc I don't think your Cauchy-Schwarz inequality section is correct. Consider the matrix `[[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0]]` which is obviously rank 2 (the third row is 0), but your checks would give `r1.r2 - r1.r1 * r2.r2 == -1`, `r1.r3 - r1.r1 * r3.r3 == -1` and `r2.r3 - r2.r2 * r3.r3 == -1`. The check you have can only detect if one vector is a (positive) multiple of another vector, but vectors can be linearly dependent without any of them being co-linear.

Comment: @SirGuy the vector of only zeros, is parallel to all other vectors in that vector space, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality . i.e. the inner product <0,a> = ||0|| ||a||  for all vectors a.

Comment: Okay, it seems like this Cauchy-Schwarz method only works for matrices of zeroes and ones. This doesn't seem to work for anything more general.

Comment: I think these two methods are slower than using Gaussian elimination to find the reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Good approach, and plus one from me. However, you have missed something: According to the original equation in the same link you provided, the inner product should be in its absolute value, thus: `-1 and 1.00004` are dependent. You should change it to `if abs(abs(inner_product) - (norm1 * norm2)) < 1e-05`

Comment: Also, the threshold `1E-5` is inconsistent. For example it returns more False Positives with datasets that have range `]0-1[` and more False Negatives with datasets that have high range, say for e.g. `[1000, 5000]`. The solution is to change from subtraction to division. For example do like this:  `if abs(inner_product) > (norm1 * norm2): if ((norm1 * norm2)/abs(inner_product)) >= 0.999995: count += 1 break` 
`else: if (abs(inner_product)/(norm1 * norm2)) >= 0.999995: `count += 1 break`

Comment: or better scaling the data into a specific range then applying the proper ratio.

Comment: suppose column (or row) X is a linear combination of 2*ColumnY and 3*ColumnZ.  Then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality would fail.

Answer (score 33):

With [sympy](/questions/tagged/sympy) you can find the linear independant rows using: [`sympy.Matrix.rref`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/matrices.html#rref):

```
>>> import sympy 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mat = np.array([[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1]])  # your matrix
>>> _, inds = sympy.Matrix(mat).T.rref()   # to check the rows you need to transpose!
>>> inds
[0, 1, 3]
```

Which basically tells you the rows 0, 1 and 3 are linear independant while row 2 isn't (it's a linear combination of row 0 and 1).

Then you could remove these rows with slicing:

```
>>> mat[inds]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

This also works well for rectangular (not only for quadratic) matrices.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand why this doesn't work for simple case:
col1 col2 col3
6 0.0789 0.9211
-1 0.0000 1.0000
24 0.0233 0.9767

Comment: Probably because you use floating point math. But you would get more accurate answers if you ask a new question including an [mcve].

Comment: Is the transposition with .T really necessary in order for it to work ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger As far as I understand it `rref` is column-based not row-based. So the `.T` is needed. But I may be wrong. It's been a while since I've written this answer.

Comment: @ChristianSinger you do need to transpose, because otherwise you get a different result (0,1, 2).

Comment: this seems to be not so accurate. e.g. this matrix `np.array([[-5,3,2],[4,-6,3],[1,3,-5]])` returns `(0,1)` while the same matrix divided by 10, i.e. `[[-.5,.3,.2],[.4,-.6,.3],[.1,.3,-.5]]` returns `(0,1,2)`

Answer (score 6):

I edited the code for Cauchy-Schwartz inequality which scales better with dimension: the inputs are the matrix and its dimension, while the output is a new rectangular matrix which contains along its rows the linearly independent columns of the starting matrix. This works in the assumption that the first column in never null, but can be readily generalized in order to implement this case too. Another thing that I observed is that 1e-5 seems to be a "sloppy" threshold, since some particular pathologic vectors were found to be linearly dependent in that case: 1e-4 doesn't give me the same problems. I hope this could be of some help: it was pretty difficult for me to find a really working routine to extract li vectors, and so I'm willing to share mine. If you find some bug, please report them!!

```
from numpy import dot, zeros
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank, norm

def find_li_vectors(dim, R):

    r = matrix_rank(R) 
    index = zeros( r ) #this will save the positions of the li columns in the matrix
    counter = 0
    index[0] = 0 #without loss of generality we pick the first column as linearly independent
    j = 0 #therefore the second index is simply 0

    for i in range(R.shape[0]): #loop over the columns
        if i != j: #if the two columns are not the same
            inner_product = dot( R[:,i], R[:,j] ) #compute the scalar product
            norm_i = norm(R[:,i]) #compute norms
            norm_j = norm(R[:,j])

            #inner product and the product of the norms are equal only if the two vectors are parallel
            #therefore we are looking for the ones which exhibit a difference which is bigger than a threshold
            if absolute(inner_product - norm_j * norm_i) > 1e-4:
                counter += 1 #counter is incremented
                index[counter] = i #index is saved
                j = i #j is refreshed
            #do not forget to refresh j: otherwise you would compute only the vectors li with the first column!!

    R_independent = zeros((r, dim))

    i = 0
    #now save everything in a new matrix
    while( i < r ):
        R_independent[i,:] = R[index[i],:] 
        i += 1

    return R_independent
```

Comment: Works great for me, thank you. Small bug: you should import "norm" from numpy.linalg instead of from numpy

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks! I probably changed the code without re-running it and forgot the .linalg.

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked a while ago, but here is a very simple (although probably inefficient) solution. Given an array, the following finds a set of linearly independent vectors by progressively adding a vector and testing if the rank has increased:

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank

def LI_vecs(dim,M):
    LI=[M[0]]
    for i in range(dim):
        tmp=[]
        for r in LI:
            tmp.append(r)
        tmp.append(M[i])                #set tmp=LI+[M[i]]
        if matrix_rank(tmp)>len(LI):    #test if M[i] is linearly independent from all (row) vectors in LI
            LI.append(M[i])             #note that matrix_rank does not need to take in a square matrix
    return LI                           #return set of linearly independent (row) vectors

#Example
mat=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[5,7,9,11],[2,4,6,8]]
LI_vecs(4,mat)
```

Comment: How efficient is this? My thought is calling `matrix_rank` is going to be very expensive.

Comment: @Annan matrix_rank is computed using the singular value decomposition, so my guess (from the standard algorithm described on wikipedia) is that it is at most O(n^3), for n the dimension of the matrix. This shouldn't be so bad, but I don't know in practice.

Comment: your function has an undefined variable `M`. Please edit code to define M or map `mat` to `M` as I think what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

I interpret the problem as finding rows that are linearly independent from other rows.
That is equivalent to finding rows that are linearly dependent on other rows.

Gaussian elimination and treat numbers smaller than a threshold as zeros can do that. It is faster than finding eigenvalues of a matrix, testing all combinations of rows with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, or singular value decomposition.

See:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297437/using-gauss-elimination-to-check-for-linear-dependence

Problem with floating point numbers:

http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Reduced-row-echelon-form-td16486.html

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the following discussion:

[Find dependent rows/columns of a matrix using Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547255/find-dependent-rows-columns-of-a-matrix-using-matlab)

```
from sympy import *
A = Matrix([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[1,7,5]])
print(A.nullspace())
```

It is obvious that the first and second row are multiplication of each other.
If we execute the above code we get `[-1/3, -2/3, 1]`. The indices of the zero elements in the null space show independence. But why is the third element here not zero? If we multiply the A matrix with the null space, we get a zero column vector. So what's wrong?

The answer which we are looking for is the null space of the transpose of A.

```
B = A.T
print(B.nullspace())
```

Now we get the `[-2, 1, 0]`, which shows that the third row is independent.

Two important notes here:

1. Consider whether we want to check the row dependencies or the column
   dependencies.
2. Notice that the null space of a matrix is not equal to the null
   space of the transpose of that matrix unless it is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically find the vectors spanning the columnspace of the matrix by using [SymPy library](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/matrices.html#columnspace)'s `columnspace()` method of Matrix object. Automatically, they are the linearly independent columns of the matrix.

```
import sympy as sp 
import numpy as np 

M  = sp.Matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1]])


for i in M.columnspace():
    print(np.array(i))
    print()

# The output is following.

# [[0]
#  [0]
#  [1]]

# [[1]
#  [0]
#  [0]]

# [[0]
#  [1]
#  [0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A (possibly) shorter solution:

```
def cartesian_product(vec1, vec2):
    return np.transpose(np.array([np.repeat(vec1, len(vec2)), np.tile(vec2, len(vec1))]))

def check_dependencies(matrix_):
    def rows_are_dependent(indices):
        if indices[0] == indices[1]:
            return False
        return np.unique(matrix_[indices[0],] / matrix_[indices[1],]).shape[0] == 1

    return np.any(np.apply_along_axis(rows_are_dependent, 1, cartesian_product(np.arange(matrix_.shape[0]), np.arange(matrix_.shape[0]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use rank to check linear dependency/ independency.

If the rank of the matrix is less than the dimension of the matrix (in a square matrix) or rank is less than the min(dim(matrix)) then the matrix is linearly dependent.

### Eg. for a square matrix like in ur example

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1]
    ])

rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(matrix)

#Check if the matrix is linearly independent
if rank == matrix.shape[0]:
    print("The matrix is linearly independent.")
else:
    print("The matrix is linearly dependent.")
```

### Eg. for a non-square matrix

```
matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]
    ])
rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(matrix)

# Check if the matrix is linearly independent

if rank == min(matrix.shape):
    print("The matrix is linearly independent.")
else:
    print("The matrix is linearly dependent.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses numpy and the $QR$ decomposition to find the linearly independent and dependent columns in a matrix $A$. $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix whose columns span the range of $A$. $R$ is an upper triangular matrix which shows how to obtain the columns of $A$ as linear combinations of the columns of $Q$. The first couple of columns of $R$ with non-zero diagonal entries are the linearly independent columns of $A$, while the rest are linearly dependent.

E.g.

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3]
              [4, 5 , 6]])
```

In this case $R$ is:

```
 R =  np.array([[-4.12310563, -5.33578375, -6.54846188],
                [ 0.        , -0.72760688, -1.45521375]])
```

Since the diagonal entries are non-zero, the first two columns of $A$ are linearly independent, and the third is linearly dependent.