# Routine to extract linear independent rows from a rank deficient matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I'm struggling with the following problem: I have some very big matrices (say, at least, 2000x2000, and probably in the future they will even reach 10000x10000) with very small rank (2 or 3, call it N) and I need to find an efficient Python routine to extract the linear independent rows (or columns, the matrix is symmetric!) From them. I tried to take the first N columns of the Q matrix of QR decomposition but it seems not to work correctly (is this wrong maybe?).

Here's the Python code I use to implement the method suggested by Ami Tavory:

```
from numpy import absolute
from numpy.linalg import qr

q = qr(R)[1] #R is my matrix
q = absolute(q)
sums = sum(q,axis=1)

i = 0
while( i < dim ): #dim is the matrix dimension
    if(sums[i] > 1.e-10):
       print "%d is a good index!" % i
    i += 1
```

This should tell me if the row is non-zero and therefore if the I-th column of R is linearly independent.

Answer (score 10):

The [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) finds a basis (equivalently largest independent subset) using linear combinations, and the [QR Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) effectively mimics this.

Therefore, one way to do what you want is to apply [`numpy.linalg.qr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) to the transpose, and check the non-zero components of the *R* matrix. The corresponding columns (in the transpose matrix, i.e., the rows in your original matrix) are independent.

---

**Edit** After some searching, I believe [this Berkeley lecture](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_mats_qr.html) explains it, but here are examples

```
import numpy as np

# 2nd column is redundant
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
>> np.linalg.qr(a)[1] # 2nd row empty
array([[ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678]])

# 3rd column is redundant
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], ])
>> np.linalg.qr(a)[1] # 3rd row empty
array([[ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        , -0.70710678],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])

# No column redundant
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4], ])
>> np.linalg.qr(a)[1] # No row empty
array([[ 2.44948974,  2.44948974,  3.67423461],
   [ 0.        ,  1.73205081,  1.73205081],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678]])
```

Comment: Thank you! By "the corresponding components" you mean the columns/rows of the starting matrix or the ones of the R matrix? Sorry I never used this method before...

Comment: Hold on, I'll try to find a link for you, if you're unfamiliar with this method.

Comment: Very kind! Because it's still not really clear to me what I should look for in R and how to transpose the result in the starting matrix.

Comment: @SimoneBolognini See if the examples help.

Comment: If I get correctly, your method suggests to look for the non null rows of the R matrix, whose index should correspond to the indices of the linearly independent columns of my starting matrix. I tried it, and it seems not to work: I know that my matrix has rank = 2 but still I find 6 non null rows, and just one of them corresponds to one of the two real independent vectors. The other one (which I know is found in the bottom of the matrix) is never considered. Any clue?

Comment: @SimoneBolognini Can you post some minimal example showing the problem? You don't necessarily have to do it here if it's too big; some pastebin or gist will do as well.

Comment: My matrix is 1656x1656... if you want I can load the .txt file on dropbox and post the link here for the download and edit the post with the python snippet with the code I use.. is it ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81765/discussion-between-ami-tavory-and-simone-bolognini).

Comment: Why are your examples of redundant columns just zeroes? If you change them to non-zero redundant values the method appears to stop working. I tested with `[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,1]]`. When you look at the R matrix there are no columns or rows near zero. Also it appears the link to Berkeley is broken.

Comment: Fyi, the link to the lecture is dead.

Comment: Hi, 
In your second example `a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], ])`, the 2nd column is redundant, not the 3rd one!
This is because `np.array` interprets vectors as *columns* but not rows. If you execute `print(a)` for all your three examples, you can see the vectors you gave to it vertically.
Plus, if you want to discover independent columns using QR, you should look at *pivot columns* in R; zero rows show free rows.

Comment: More info: [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748500/how-to-find-linearly-independent-columns-in-a-matrix/748538#748538) and [Lecture 17: Orthogonal matrices and Gram-Schmidt](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-17-orthogonal-matrices-and-gram-schmidt)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link where I found a solution to my problem! The Cauchy-Schwartz method proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816627/how-to-find-linearly-independent-rows-from-a-matrix) works just fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example demonstrating Ami's suggestion of using the QR decomp and taking non-null rows of R doesn't work as described:

```
# 2 dependent rows
>> A = array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
              [-1., -1.,  0.,  0.]])
# looks like it works for this case
>> numpy.linalg.qr(A.T)[1]
array([[-1.41421356,  1.41421356], 
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ]])

# counter example
>> A2 = numpy.array([[1,1,0,0.],[-1,-1,0,0.],[1,2,3,4]])
>> numpy.linalg.qr(A2.T)[1] 
array([[-1.41421356,  1.41421356, -2.12132034],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678], # 2nd row is not null
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -5.        ]])
```

The second pivot is missing, it's possible there is some structure here that could be used but not the rows.