# Remove duplicate rows of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I remove duplicate rows of a 2 dimensional `numpy` array?

```
data = np.array([[1,8,3,3,4],
                 [1,8,9,9,4],
                 [1,8,3,3,4]])
```

The answer should be as follows:

```
ans = array([[1,8,3,3,4],
             [1,8,9,9,4]])
```

If there are two rows that are the same, then I would like to remove one "duplicate" row.

Comment: Is it okay if the rows are not in that order orginally present in input array?

Comment: yes,    order is not important

Comment: My problem is very similar to yours. [Look here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093261/python-routine-to-extract-linear-independent-rows-from-a-rank-deficient-matrix/31093331?noredirect=1#comment50210205_31093331

Comment: I believe now you can apply ```np.unique``` over an axis, so

```np.unique(data, axis = 0)```

works.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use `numpy unique`. Since you want the unique rows, we need to put them into tuples:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,8,3,3,4],
                 [1,8,9,9,4],
                 [1,8,3,3,4]])
```

***just applying `np.unique` to the `data`*** array will result in this:

```
>>> uniques
array([1, 3, 4, 8, 9])
```

***prints out the unique elements in the list***. So putting them into tuples results in:

```
new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
uniques = np.unique(new_array)
```

which prints:

```
>>> uniques
array([[1, 8, 3, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 9, 9, 4]])
```

**UPDATE**

In the new version, you need to set `np.unique(data, axis=0)`

Comment: I tried  `new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
uniques = np.unique(new_array)` but it still output uniques `array([1, 3, 4, 8, 9])` @ThePredator

Comment: @Owen: That cannot be possible, check your code once more.

Comment: Here is the code, I used the same code as your show:


`import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,8,3,3,4],
                 [1,8,9,9,4],
                 [1,8,3,3,4]])

new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
uniques = np.unique(new_array)
uniques
Out[30]: array([1, 3, 4, 8, 9])`   Is that anything about the numpy version? my numpy version is 1.9.2

Comment: @Owen: I have no idea!

Comment: In numpy 1.9.0, the help states that it flattens the input, however omerbp's solution works.

Comment: A couple of years late, but It doesn't work for me

```y = [np.random.randint(0, 3, 2) for i in range(20)]

new_y = [tuple(element) for element in y]

set(new_y)```

or if you need it as a list:

`list(set(new_y))`

Comment: I think the following is the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array

Comment: In the new version, you need to set `np.unique(data, axis=0)`

Comment: I think that this was for an outdated version. It is better to use what @Justas put .

Comment: Note that Divakar's `lexsort` solution is still the fastest presented here (at least for this example).

Answer (score 27):

One approach with [`lex-sorting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) -

```
# Perform lex sort and get sorted data
sorted_idx = np.lexsort(data.T)
sorted_data =  data[sorted_idx,:]

# Get unique row mask
row_mask = np.append([True],np.any(np.diff(sorted_data,axis=0),1))

# Get unique rows
out = sorted_data[row_mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [199]: data
Out[199]: 
array([[1, 8, 3, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 9, 9, 4],
       [1, 8, 3, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 3, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 9, 9, 4]])

In [200]: sorted_idx = np.lexsort(data.T)
     ...: sorted_data =  data[sorted_idx,:]
     ...: row_mask = np.append([True],np.any(np.diff(sorted_data,axis=0),1))
     ...: out = sorted_data[row_mask]
     ...: 

In [201]: out
Out[201]: 
array([[1, 8, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 3, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 9, 9, 4]])
```

Runtime tests -

This section times all approaches proposed in the solutions presented thus far.

```
In [34]: data = np.random.randint(0,10,(10000,10))

In [35]: def tuple_based(data):
    ...:     new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
    ...:     return np.unique(new_array)
    ...: 
    ...: def lexsort_based(data):                 
    ...:     sorted_data =  data[np.lexsort(data.T),:]
    ...:     row_mask = np.append([True],np.any(np.diff(sorted_data,axis=0),1))
    ...:     return sorted_data[row_mask]
    ...: 
    ...: def unique_based(a):
    ...:     a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    ...:     unique_a = np.unique(a.view([('', a.dtype)]*a.shape[1]))
    ...:     return unique_a.view(a.dtype).reshape((unique_a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))
    ...: 

In [36]: %timeit tuple_based(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.1 ms per loop

In [37]: %timeit lexsort_based(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.92 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit unique_based(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: f.y.i.: `unique_based` is about twice as fast as `np.unique(data, axis=0)`, so lexsort is still preferable in 2022.

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution can be:

```
import numpy as np
def unique_rows(a):
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    unique_a = np.unique(a.view([('', a.dtype)]*a.shape[1]))
    return unique_a.view(a.dtype).reshape((unique_a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))

data = np.array([[1,8,3,3,4],
                 [1,8,9,9,4],
                 [1,8,3,3,4]])


print unique_rows(data)
#prints:
[[1 8 3 3 4]
 [1 8 9 9 4]]
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560440/removing-duplicate-columns-and-rows-from-a-numpy-2d-array) for many more solutions for this problem