# How to remove duplicates from a 3D array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array as follow, 'b', which I want to represent an array of 2-D array. I want to remove the duplicates of my 2-D arrays and get the unique ones.

```
>>> a = [[[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]]
>>> b = numpy.array(a)
>>> b
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [4, 5]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2]]])
```

In this above example, I really want to return the following because there exist one duplicate which I want to remove.

```
unique = array([[[1, 2],
                 [1, 2]],

                 [[1, 2],
                  [4, 5]])
```

How should do this with numpy package? Thanks

Comment: Curious if any of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

See previous answer: [Remove duplicate rows of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097247/remove-duplicate-rows-of-a-numpy-array)
convert to array of tuples and then apply np.unique()

Answer (score 0):

Reshape, find the unique rows, then reshape again.

Finding unique tuples by converting to a set.

```
import numpy as np
a = [[[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]]
b = np.array(a)

new_array = [tuple(row) for row in b.reshape(3,4)]
uniques = list(set(new_array))

output = np.array(uniques).reshape(len(uniques), 2, 2)
output

Out[131]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [4, 5]]])
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work:

`ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-191-754759117946> in <module>()
      6 uniques = np.unique(new_array)
      7 
----> 8 output = uniques.reshape(len(uniques), 2, 2)
      9 output

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (4,2,2)`

Comment: Good point.  Fixed now to use a `set` to find uniques.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to tuple and back again is probably going to be quire expensive, instead you can do a generalized view:

```
def unique_by_first(a):
    tmp = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(tmp).view(np.dtype((np.void, tmp.dtype.itemsize * tmp.shape[1])))
    _, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    return  a[idx].reshape(-1, *a.shape[1:])
```

Usage:

```
print unique_by_first(a) 
[[[1 2]
  [1 2]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]]]
```

Effectively, a generalization of previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each such 2D slice off the last two axes into a scalar each by considering them as indices on a multi-dimensional grid. The intention is to map each such slice to a scalar based on their uniqueness. Then, using those scalars, we could use `np.unique` to keep one instance only.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
idx = np.ravel_multi_index(a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1).T,a.max(0).ravel()+1)
out = a[np.sort(np.unique(idx, return_index=1)[1])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: a
Out[43]: 
array([[[8, 1],
        [2, 8]],

       [[3, 8],
        [3, 4]],

       [[2, 4],
        [1, 0]],

       [[3, 0],
        [4, 8]],

       [[2, 4],
        [1, 0]],

       [[8, 1],
        [2, 8]]])

In [44]: idx = np.ravel_multi_index(a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1).T,a.max(0).ravel()+1)

In [45]: a[np.sort(np.unique(idx, return_index=1)[1])]
Out[45]: 
array([[[8, 1],
        [2, 8]],

       [[3, 8],
        [3, 4]],

       [[2, 4],
        [1, 0]],

       [[3, 0],
        [4, 8]]])
```

If you don't mind the order of such slices being maintained, skip the `np.sort()` at the last step.