# Python - remove row duplications by part of the row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[51001, 121, 1, 121212],
                 [51001, 121, 1, 125451],
                 [51001, 125, 1, 127653]]
```

I want to remove duplicate rows only by the first 3 elements in a row (first 3 columns).

So the result I will get is:

```
print data
[[51001, 121, 1, 121212],
 [51001, 125, 1, 127653]]
```

Doesn't matter which row we keep and which row we delete as long as I get the unique by the first 3 columns

Comment: Slice the first three cols and use the linked dup Q&As.

Comment: I Can slice but I dont know how to maintain the 4th column and I didnt see any answer about how to do it

Comment: From this [`answer post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31097280/3293881), edit : `sorted_idx = np.lexsort(data[:,:3].T)` and `row_mask = np.append([True],np.any(np.diff(sorted_data[:,:3],axis=0),1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `drop_duplicates` in pandas

```
In [179]: pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates([0, 1, 2]).values
Out[179]:
array([[ 51001,    121,      1, 121212],
       [ 51001,    125,      1, 127653]])
```