# Remove duplicate tuples in numpy array (ones directly next to each other)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I am more or less new to python/numpy and I have this problem:

I have numpy arrays in which the first and last tuples are always the same. In between, there are sometimes duplicate tuples (only the ones directly next to each other) that I want to get rid of. The used parenthesis structure should be maintained.

I tried `np.unique` already (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097247/remove-duplicate-rows-of-a-numpy-array), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637336/numpy-unique-with-order-preserved)), but it changes my original order (which has to be maintained). My sample array looks like this:

```
    myarray = np.array([[[1,1],[1,1],[4,4],[4,4],[2,2],[3,3],[1,1]]])
```

I need a result that looks like this:

```
    myarray = np.array([[[1,1],[4,4],[2,2],[3,3],[1,1]]])
```

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: i think your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097247/remove-duplicate-rows-of-a-numpy-array

Comment: OP needs to preserve original order, which `np.unique()` will not do.

Comment: @VanDeWack `In between, there are sometimes duplicate tuples (only the **ones directly next to each other)**`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy.unique with order preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637336/numpy-unique-with-order-preserved)

Comment: @SBylemans Again, the linked Q&A doesn't deal with  **ones directly next to each other)** criteria.

Comment: @Divakar true, I flagged it as such regarding his comment `I tried np.unique already, but it changes my original order (which has to be maintained).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the one-off offsetted comparisons along the second axis and use boolean-indexing to select -

```
myarray[:,np.r_[True,(myarray[0,1:] != myarray[0,:-1]).any(-1)]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: myarray
Out[42]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [4, 4],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [1, 1]]])

In [43]: myarray[:,np.r_[True,(myarray[0,1:] != myarray[0,:-1]).any(-1)]]
Out[43]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [1, 1]]])
```

Or with equality comparison and then look for `ALL` matches -

```
In [47]: myarray[:,np.r_[True,~((myarray[0,1:] == myarray[0,:-1]).all(-1))]]
Out[47]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [1, 1]]])
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the solution that I needed. Both versions work for me, thanks!