# Find Columns that are Linear Combinations of Other Columns

Tags: r, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm fairly new to statistics and sklearn, so please forgive me if this is a very basic question. I have a m x n matrix (thousands of rows, hundreds of columns) and I'm trying to find the columns within the matrix that are linear combinations of other columns in the matrix so that they can be flagged and removed.

In R, I was able to use the lm() function and find variables with NA coefficients to find variables that were linear combinations of other variables, but the sklearn linear regression is based on a different implementation that returns different results.

So far I've tried playing around with QR Decomposition to find linearly independent and dependent columns, but the results have not been correct (for example below, I ran np.linalg.qr() on a matrix with a column of all 1s, and it did not flag column d as a "bad" column).

I'm doing this in order to determine if a given matrix is rank deficient, and which columns can be removed. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with my QR decomposition or if there is another method to determining whether a matrix is rank deficient/which columns are linear combinations of others?

Small QR Decomposition Attempt (found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093261/python-routine-to-extract-linear-independent-rows-from-a-rank-deficient-matrix)):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

a = [546, 42, 68, 15, 47, 12, 154, 45]
b = [4, 6, 34, 2, 8, 24, 35, 93]
c = [44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 12, 41, 32]
d = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
e = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.1]
f = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.01]
g = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.001]


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a,
                 'b': b,
                 'c': c,
                 'd': d,
                 'e': e,
                 'f': f,
                 'g': g })


# get R matrix from QR decomposition
R = np.linalg.qr(df)[1] 
R = abs(R)
sums = R.sum(axis=1)

columns = df.columns.tolist()

i = 0
# rows with sum near 0 are linearly dependent column in the 
# original matrix
while( i < df.shape[1] ): 
    if(sums[i] > 1.e-10):
        print("{} is a good column!".format(columns[i]))
    else:
        print("{} is a bad column!".format(columns[i]))
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
a is a good column!
b is a good column!
c is a good column!
d is a good column!
e is a good column!
f is a bad column!
g is a bad column!
```

In R, the output on this dataset is the same, except col d is flagged as bad (as it should be since it's a column of all 1s).

Comment: I would use LU decomposition (easier to compute) instead of QR; an example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42868363), scipy/numpy only.

Comment: What formula did you give `lm()`? Normally, R adds intercept (a column of all ones) unless told otherwise.