# Is there a way to check for linearly dependent columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-algebra

Is there a way to check for linear dependency for columns in a pandas dataframe? For example:

```
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df.A = [0,2,3,4]
df.B = df.A*2
df.C = [8,3,5,4]
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  0  0  8
1  2  4  3
2  3  6  5
3  4  8  4
```

Is there a way to show that column `B` is a linear combination of `A`, but `C` is an independent column? My ultimate goal is to run a poisson regression on a dataset, but I keep getting a `LinAlgError: Singular matrix` error, meaning no inverse exists of my dataframe and thus it contains dependent columns.

I would like to come up with a programmatic way to check each feature and ensure there are no dependent columns.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you need with `numpy` and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816627/how-to-find-linearly-independent-rows-from-a-matrix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `SymPy` you could use the ["reduced row echelon form"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) via [`sympy.matrix.rref`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/matrices.html#rref):

```
>>> import sympy 
>>> reduced_form, inds = sympy.Matrix(df.values).rref()
>>> reduced_form
Matrix([
[1.0, 2.0,   0],
[  0,   0, 1.0],
[  0,   0,   0],
[  0,   0,   0]])

>>> inds
[0, 2]
```

The pivot columns (stored as `inds`) represent the "column numbers" that are linear independent, and you could simply "slice away" the other ones:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, inds]
   A  C
0  0  8
1  2  3
2  3  5
3  4  4
```

Comment: Is there a way when `SymPy` is not available?