# Linear Dependence of Set of Vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check whether some vectors are dependent on each other or not by numpy, I found some good suggestions for checking linear dependency of rows of a matrix in the link below:
[How to find linearly independent rows from a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816627/how-to-find-linearly-independent-rows-from-a-matrix)

I can not understand the 'Cauchy-Schwarz inequality' method which I think is due to lack of my knowledge, however I tried the Eigenvalue method to check linear dependency among columns and here is my code:

```
A = np.array([
              [0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1]
])

lambdas, V = np.linalg.eig(A)
print(lambdas)
print(V)
```

and I get:

```
[ 1.          0.          1.61803399 -0.61803399]
[[ 0.          0.70710678  0.2763932  -0.7236068 ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.4472136   0.4472136 ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.7236068  -0.2763932 ]
 [ 1.         -0.70710678  0.4472136   0.4472136 ]]
```

My question is what is the relevance between these eigenvectors or eigenvalues to the dependency of columns of my matrix? How can I understand which columns are dependent to each other and which are independent by these values?

Comment: Note that in the linked answer, you should use `np.linalg.eig(A.T)` (the transpose!) to work on the rows

Comment: Your final question doesn't make sense: an eigenvalue does not "belong to" a column of the matrix. Perhaps you want to find a combination of rows that illustrates the linear dependence? Please can you edit your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second column vector corresponds to the eigenvalue of 0.

Just take a look at the [API documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) when you get confused.

> v : (…, M, M) array
>
> The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column
> v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i].

Answer (score 0):

You can find the linearly independent columns by QR decomposition as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748500/how-to-find-linearly-independent-columns-in-a-matrix/748538#748538).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).