# Detect which columns of matrix are linearly dependent in lapack

Tags: lapack

I have a square matrix (nxn) and I know that its rank < n. I also know that one of its column can be expressed as linear combination of few other columns (< n-1). for e.g. if I have a 5x5 matrix then its column 2 can be expressed as combination of column 1 and column 3. 
I want to find a way to detect these linearly dependent columns. An answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548118/8245075 does the exact job I want. However, I am programming in C and using lapack routines for linear algebra.

How to do this in lapack ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what you would like. It should be clear that if `c2` is a linear combination of `c1` and `c3` (`c2=a c1 + b c3`), then `c1` can be written as a linear combination of `c2` and `c3` (dito `c3`). Are you searching for a set of vectors which span the vector space given by the columns of your matrix?

Comment: @kvantour: Going by your notations, I want to detect c1, c2 and c3 columns out of the 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Do an Eigenvalue decomposition (choose appropriate here: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen.html - these are the real double percision drivers). The cols (transposed => rows) with eigenvalue 0 are linearly dependant on others.